# How to print a list in HTML using Jinja template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I've a list `data = [[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,5]],["abc","def"]]` . I want to print data[1][0], ie "abc" to the HTML template. How can I do that without using loops?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#variables):

> You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable, alternative [sic] the so-called “subscript” syntax ([]) can be used.

The example given is the following, which it claims are equivalent:

```
{{ foo.bar }}
{{ foo['bar'] }}
```

So, you can do what you're looking for with either syntax, as shown below...

```
from jinja2 import Template

data = [[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,5]],["abc","def"]]

t1 = Template('Printing {{data.1.0}}')
t2 = Template('Printing {{data[1][0]}}')

t1.render(data=data) # Returns u'printing abc'
t2.render(data=data) # Also returns u'printing agc'
```

Comment: I send the data from the views.py file to the template and then called {{data[1][0]}} inside the .HTML file , but it throws an error.

Comment: Then you need to use the error to help figure out your problem, or post another question with the full details of your template and the full error that you are getting if you need help figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the same way as in normal python?

```
import jinja2
template = """
    {{ data[1][0] }}
"""

data = [[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,5]],["abc","def"]]
print(jinja2.Template(template).render(data=data))
```

That works to me.